# Should I rely on MySQL errors in PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if logic duplication can be reduced on this one. Let's say I have a `users` table and `email` column, which should be unique per record. What I normally do, is having a unique index on the column and validation code that checks if the value is already used:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = 'foo@bar.com')
```

Is it possible and practical to skip the explicit check and just rely on the database error when trying to put non-unique value? If we repeat the logic of uniqueness in two layers (database and application code), it's not really DRY.

Comment: nice way, i don't have exact answer but 
u may need to run 2 query's every'time to check if exist and then retrieve data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that pretty often. In my custom database class I throw a specific exception for violated restrictions (this can be easily deduced from the numeric error code returned by MySQL) and I catch such exception upon insert.

It has the benefit of simplicity and it also prevents race conditions—MySQL takes care of data integrity in both variants, data itself and concurrent accesses.

The only drawback is that it can be tricky to figure out which index is failing when you have more than one (for instance, you may want to have a unique email and a unique username). MySQL drivers only report the violated key name in the *text* of the error message, there's no specific API for it.

In any case, you may want to inform the user about available names in an earlier stage, so a prior check can also make sense.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I was pretty sure MySQL error coded are way to go. Thank you for opening my eyes for more than one unique index per table.

Comment: I'm always annoyed about poor communication between SQL databases and code. This was just an example, but what annoys me even more are foreign keys, which are not trivial to read. Every ORM I've heard of just duplicates the logic of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to enforce the uniqueness of the email address in the database. Only that way you can be sure it is really unique.

If you do it only in the PHP code then any error in that code may corrupt the database.

Doing it in both is not needed but does, in my opinion, not offend against the DRY rule. For instance, you might want to check the presence of an email address during registration of a new user, and not only rely on the database reporting an error.

Comment: I'm aware that doing it only on PHP side is bad idea and I always do it on the database as well. If I wanted to just check it, there would be no question. :)

Answer (score 0):

On top of the database constraint, you should check if the email given already exists in it before trying to insert. Handling it that way is cleaner and allows for better validation and response for the client, without throwing an error.

The same goes for classic constraints such as MIN / MAX (note that such constraints are ignored on MySQL). You should check, validate and return a validation error message to the client before committing any change to the database.

Comment: It's up to you if you throw an error or not, so it doesn't help.

Comment: To me, it's better to avoid throwing an exception if you can. Also every PHP frameworks I know do it this way.

Comment: Min and max are not even possible to force on the database layer.

Comment: It's quite possible that it's "better" to avoid exceptions, but the question is why.

Comment: Indeed check constraints are ignored on mysql. Sorry about that.  
About exceptions, if you are using an error tracking mechanism, it can be tricky to exclude a specific one from the process, and lead to unclear code. In fact that depends on how you handle exceptions in the first place.

Comment: It would be nice if database layer could be programmed to always contain good data, no matter the way we insert them. But that's not possible, so I guess we need to treat database just as a service, which it is. Worth asking though, as I'm always in pain when I need to state something twice, like in my example above.

Comment: You may be interested in databases which handle constraints then, such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)

Comment: I have never used it, I will definitely check it out, thanks!

Comment: I understand that doesn't answer the question but I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "DRY" you mean Don't Repeat Yourself. Applying the same logic in more than one place is not intrinsically bad - there's the old adage "measure twice, cut once".

In a more general case, I usually follow the pattern of applying the insert and catching the constraint violation, but for users with email addresses it's a much more complicated story. If your email is the *only* attribute required to be unique, then we can skip over a lot of discussion about a person having more than one account and working out which attribute is not unique when a constraint violation is reported. That the email is the only unqiue attribute is implied in your question, but not stated.

Based on your comments you appear to be sending this SQL from your PHP code. Given that, there are 2 real issues with polling the record first:

1) Performance and Capacity: it's an extra round trip, parse and read operation on the database

2) Security: Giving your application user direct access (particularly to tables controlling access) is not good for security. Its is much safer to encapsulate this as a stored procedure/function running with definer privileges and returning messages more aligned to the application logic. Even if you still go down the route of implementing poll first / insert if absent, you are eliminating most of the overhead in issue 1.

You might also spend a moment considering the difference between your query and...

```
 SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `email` = 'foo@bar.com'
```

Comment: I don't think "measure twice, cut once" applies here. Validation rules are like cutting in this case.

Comment: Are you sure `SELECT 1` will be faster than `SELECT EXISTS`? I think there is a lot of performance magic going on behind `SELECT EXISTS`. Plus, doesn't your query need `LIMIT 1`? I'm not sure if unique index skips processing when one is matched, I guess not.

Comment: No, SELECT 1 is no faster than SELECT EXiSTS, but its a lot ligher than using a sub query AND selecting all the attributes, but its not a big overhead. And as per answer above, your question is predicated on email address being unique - hence LIMIT 1 in the query is more redundancy.

Comment: `SELECT EXISTS` doesn't select all attributes. Quote: *Traditionally, an EXISTS subquery starts with SELECT *, but it could begin with SELECT 5 or SELECT column1 or anything at all. MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference.*